# Ordenar consulta SQL Access desde dos columnas

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo la siguiente consulta montada en Access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.DESTINO, muelles.ORDEN_TMP
FROM (preparaciones INNER JOIN detalle_prep ON preparaciones.N_PREP = detalle_prep.N_PREP) INNER JOIN muelles ON detalle_prep.DESTINO = muelles.M_ADAIA
GROUP BY preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.DESTINO, muelles.ORDEN_TMP, detalle_prep.ACCIONES, detalle_prep.PREPARADA
HAVING (((detalle_prep.ACCIONES)=True) AND ((detalle_prep.PREPARADA)=False))
ORDER BY preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.ORDEN_TMP;
```

Esto me está devolviendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo necesito que todos los registros cuyo ORDEN_TMP sea igual 99 pasen al final de la consulta, respetando la fecha. Es decir, el primer registro con fecha 23/11/2021 - VALLADOLID - 99 debería quedar por encima del registro de CADIZ, quedando los tres últimos registros así:

23/11/2021 - VALLADOLID - 99

17/12/2021 - CADIZ - 99

17/12/2021 - VALLADOLID - 99

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes buscar información sobre `IIF`. en access. De manera que puedes establecer condiciones particulares al ordenamiento. [IIF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/client-developer/access/iif-function-access-custom-web-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.DESTINO, muelles.ORDEN_TMP
FROM (preparaciones INNER JOIN detalle_prep ON preparaciones.N_PREP = detalle_prep.N_PREP) INNER JOIN muelles ON detalle_prep.DESTINO = muelles.M_ADAIA
WHERE muelles.ORDEN_TMP <> 99
GROUP BY preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.DESTINO, muelles.ORDEN_TMP, detalle_prep.ACCIONES, detalle_prep.PREPARADA
HAVING (((detalle_prep.ACCIONES)=True) AND ((detalle_prep.PREPARADA)=False))
ORDER BY preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.ORDEN_TMP
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.DESTINO, muelles.ORDEN_TMP
FROM (preparaciones INNER JOIN detalle_prep ON preparaciones.N_PREP = detalle_prep.N_PREP) INNER JOIN muelles ON detalle_prep.DESTINO = muelles.M_ADAIA
WHERE muelles.ORDEN_TMP = 99
GROUP BY preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.DESTINO, muelles.ORDEN_TMP, detalle_prep.ACCIONES, detalle_prep.PREPARADA
HAVING (((detalle_prep.ACCIONES)=True) AND ((detalle_prep.PREPARADA)=False))
ORDER BY preparaciones.FECHA, muelles.ORDEN_TMP
```

Para lograr esto utilizamos el **operador de conjuntos union**. Primero hacemos una consulta como la que tienes hecha pero en la **cláusula where** ponemos:

```
WHERE muelles.ORDEN_TMP <> 99
```

para obtener los registros cuyo **campo muelles.ORDEN_TMP** es diferente a **99**.

La segunda consulta también es igual a la que tienes hecha pero esta vez en la **cláusula where** ponemos:

```
WHERE muelles.ORDEN_TMP = 99
```

para obtener los registros cuyo **campo muelles.ORDEN_TMP** es igual a **99**.

Entonces utilizando el **operador union** concatenamos ambos resultados de cada consulta.

Para que el **operador union** funcione ambas consultas deben devolver la misma cantidad de campos y ser del mismo tipo en su correspondiente orden.

Comment: Es curioso, por separado las consultas funcionan perfecto pero al hacer la consulta de unión el resultado varía y no tengo ni idea del motivo. He probando modificando el ORDER BY en ambas, en una sola, etc. y nada de nada.

Comment: prueba con union all